# The OS X firewall causes certain applications to hang, only while AirPort is connected. How do I find the cause of this problem?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, firewall, airport

I'm experiencing three strange problems on OS X (Snow Leopard), which only appear while I am connected to a wireless network over Airport.

1. The "Security" tab in System Preferences takes about 1 minute to load, and clicking the lock to make changes also results in a long delay. (Eventually, however, everything works.)
2. I can't start Mathematica 7. The menu bar appears, but no window appears, and clicking on the menu bar results in the beach ball of death.
3. I can't save certain files in Adobe Illustrator CS 4. (The application hangs, with 0% CPU usage.)

I've tried some of the "usual" fixes, e.g. repairing permissions, and deleting plist's related to Airport. I'd really like to understand what's going on, however!

I suspect that this is in some way related to the firewall, because the Security tab in System Preferences controls the firewall, and often when I used to successfully start Mathematica 7, I would get the standard firewall dialog, asking if I wanted to allow or deny access to the application. I'm not sure what's changed recently, however.

> Can anyone diagnose this issue?

Unfortunately I can't try any alternate network connections; there's only one wireless network around here, and I'm on a Macbook Air and don't have the USB dongle to connect to Ethernet.

**UPDATE:** actually, Mathematica *does* start: after approximately 5 minutes the usual firewall dialog appears, and after clicking allow there's another, shorter, delay, and then a window opens.

Comment: Does the problem go away if you turn off the personal firewall? Also, what do the various logs (system.log, kernel.log, firewall logs) say when this slowness is going on?

Comment: No, turning off the firewall doesn't help. I haven't seen anything in the logs yet, but I haven't carefully watched them as I reproduce the problems. I'll report back if I do...